# What's The 2pt Correlation Function For The Spin Fields For The 3D Critical Ising Model?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, ising-model, correlation-functions

The title it self explanatory. What's The 2pt Correlation Function For The Spin Fields For The 3D Ising Model? I know the form of the four point function and have worked out how to express it in terms of a sum of conformal blocks. But not the 2pt function. If anyone can show me the form of it that is constrained by conformal invariance I would much appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: If you know the 4pt correlators you can extract the (squared) 2pt correlators from cluster decomposition.

Comment: That's pretty fascinating. Will that give me an exact result or an infinite series. I never did a cluster decomposition before.

Comment: Cluster decomposition says $\langle O_1 O_2 \rangle = \langle O_1 \rangle \langle O_2 \rangle$ in the limit that the supports of $O_1$ and $O_2$ are infinitely separated. Take these operators to be the 2pt spin operators and take a limit of the 4pt function where the separation within the pairs remains constant while the separation between them becomes infinite. This is something that works (at least in theory) in any QFT. I think that conformal invariance constrains the 2pt functions pretty strongly. In 1+1D it's enough to get them up to a multiplicative constant, but I don't know about 2+1D.

Answer (score 2):

In a CFT two point functions are fixed in terms of the dimension
$$
\langle \sigma(x_1)\sigma(x_2)\rangle = \frac{1}{|x_1-x_2|^{2\Delta_\sigma}}\,.
$$
Correlation functions are discussed in every review of conformal bootstrap, see e.g. [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.05000.pdf) and [2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07982.pdf).